# Creating separate tables in parse for separate set of users

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am creating an android app which is backed by parse database. In the app i have two sets of users let say Client and Merchant, now i want them to behave like a ParseUser but store them in separate tables.

I tried extending parseuser(registering subclass) in my app by client and merchant but i discovered they get stored in same table which is user table in parse.

I googled this problem but i couldn't find anything. Any help would be appreciated.

I am writing something like this to create new subclass

```
@ParseClassName("User1")
public class User1 extends ParseUser
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to register **User1.class** in your app's Application class:

```
ParseObject.registerSubclass(User1.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

All the user in Parse should be in the `_User` default class.

The best way to differentiate various types of users is to use **Roles**.
You can find out in official [roles guide](https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#roles) in the Parse documentation

Comment: this is what parse guide says - _Roles provide a logical way of grouping users with common access privileges to your Parse data._. So, it just provide a way to segregate user according to data access, what i want is different types of user for that i need to create different tables. Client will different sets of field and Merchant will have different set of fields.